# Return only first 500 characters of text

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue where I cannot select the first 500 characters of each post. (Posts are stored in a MySQL database). The code I have right now is:

```
$link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'jfairbanks_dbuser', 'password' );
mysqli_select_db( $link, 'jfairbanks_database' );
$results = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT post FROM Users where verified = 1 LIMIT 0 , 10" ); //this displayes all the posts that have been verified
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {
 $post = $record['post'];
 print $post;
}
  mysqli_free_result( $results );
mysqli_close( $link );
?>
```

That code selects all characters from all posts that are verified and that's good, but I need to restrict the length of the post that is displayed. (I want only the first 500 characters to be seen).

I tried using `LEFT(post, 500)` among other things but that did not work.

Comment: " tried using LEFT (post, 500) among other thingsenter code here but that did not work." how did it not work?

Comment: it gave me this error: Undefined index: post in *my site here*

Comment: You probably forgot to use an alias... Something like: `SELECT LEFT(post,500) AS post ...`

Comment: ok thank you Nicarus

Comment: seeing your html source from the link you left, your markup is off with a stray tag. That error you said about overlapping is an html/css issue

Comment: yeah ok i just got back on after thinking and realising that the using LEFT was also cutting out the ending tags of the posts so i simply appended them on each post that gets displayed and that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to provide an alias for your field after using the `LEFT()` function in MySQL.

Your query would look like this: `SELECT LEFT(post,500) AS post FROM Users ...`

By aliasing it with `post` you can now access it in the associative array, as you were doing before:

`$post = $record['post'];`

Without an alias in the sql query, the array does not have a key of `post` and throws the exception that you received.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function of mysql

```
SELECT LEFT(post,500) AS post FROM Users where verified = 1 LIMIT 0 , 10
```

I didn't even know PHP had a left function until your comment? Or perhaps it was something you wrote? The usual way to take a substring in PHP is to use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. But taking the substring in mysql is more efficient because there is less data been transferred.

Also note the addition of AS post to alias the generated column to post so that it can be retrieved in your PHP code.

Comment: The OP tried that already. There error was when here: `$post = $record['post'];` and `post` did not exist because it was not aliased.

Comment: *"I didn't even know PHP had a left function until your comment?"* - That's because it isn't a php function, it's an mysql function; you even included the mysql url for it. P.s.: Not my downvote here.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- his comment was misleading. Because obviously mysql wouldn't raise an undefined index error. What was missing was the alias. Addressed.

Comment: @e4c5 - OK, but you have not explained why the error occurred... I'm not 100% sure you understand OP's question.

Comment: @e4c5 an undefined index is not limited to php; it can be related to mysql also, if for instance the column does not exist or the column's case in the loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- did you mean inside a stored procedure? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @e4c5 Say for example using `SELECT post....` and using `while...($record['Post'])...` the capital "P" in there would throw an undefined index since their column is lowercased as opposed to camel case.

Comment: but @Fred-ii- that's a PHP error not a mysql error.

Comment: @e4c5 in a way, yet it's still related to the query. Bit of a delicate subject but still an undefined index. Or say if the column did not exist at all or their RDBMS is limited to letter case, then that would do it also. Rather a broad subject though.

Comment: I don't see anything delicate here @Fred-ii- that error comes well and truely from the PHP code base :-)